# Copy app to Rackspace from Different Network

Tags: 12.04, scp

I want to copy files from my system to rackspace (aws), ( there is a way to use scp but i am in my office network, rackspace bought at aws), any package is there ? for this need.

Help me to copy my app to rackspace..

Answer (score 0):

You can use scp or you could even use rsync.

I often use rsync to connect to a remote machine and send files. You will need to have access to the remote machine (i usually have ssh access via private key).

http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync

Of course if you're trying to connect to the remote server over SSH (the way rsync does) you will need access to this port (so you'll run into issues if your network blocks access).

You will need to tell us more about your individual setup if this isn't a suitable solution.